# Syntax doldrums

Tags: syntax

I am a long time user and fan of LaTeX, but I *hate* the syntax!  I wish it could be more like Python or Haskell.  The syntax of those programming languages is much more readable than LaTeX which is ironic because you are much more likely to spend time *reading* raw LaTeX than programming code.

I would like it to be something like

```
We have
\equation
    A =
    \bmatrix
        a & b
        c & d
where ...
```

Instead of

```
We have
\begin{equation}
    A =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where ...
```

This is a simple example but you all know how onerous the curly brackets \begin's and \end's  can get in complicated examples

Is there an alternative interpreter for LaTeX that has *nicer* syntax?

Comment: You can use a different markup language like Markdown. Pandoc can create LaTeX files. However you loose flexibility.

Comment: A *hate* for LaTeX syntax on a TeX & LaTeX Q&A is a very strong word to use, don't you think?

Comment: @Werner Yes!  It's like: I love my wife, but hate the way she bites her nails ... I still love my wife. :)

Comment: @StephenMcAteer: Touché, as I bite my own nails... `:-|`

Comment: Actually I would hate it if LaTeX had Python-style significant indentation.

Comment: Maybe a good compromise would be a ruby or lua style delimiters.  Write environments as `\begin{equation} ... \end`.  LaTeX already knows which environment should be ending where, as it is able to complain when you close a wrong one. Ideally it could work both ways, just `\end` would choose the right one to close, with an environment name it would check and warn you in you tried to close a wrong one.

Comment: "go away, the syntax is great".  Seriously, TeX *is not a programming language* and, more importantly, the majority of users are not programmers.  So they (we) aren't used to programming conventions.

Comment: @JanHlavacek -- if you've ever been bitten by getting out of phase with `\begin` and `\end` you'll appreciate that latex tells you what the mismatch is.  and in particular, if you've ever had to debug someone else's document that contains such a mismatch, you'll be doubly grateful.  (oh, i really prefer plain tex to latex, and personally, i dislike all the latex braces and would rather use delimited arguments.  but building a design that helps avoid inscrutable errors requires some compromise.)

Comment: @barbara: I see your point, especially the "debugging somene else's document" part, that's a very strong argument against my "give users the choice" suggestion. On the other hand, one could have a script that would replace every `\end` by `\end{environment}` so that things would balance, and indent the code properly.  Then findings problems should be fairly easy. Although I am sure you have seen plenty of documents where even that wouldn't help.

Comment: @JanHlavacek What you describe is pretty trivial to do with the xparse package. `\let\OldEnd\end\RenewDocumentCommand{\end}{g}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\OldEnd{#1}}{\expandafter\OldEnd\expandafter{\@currenvir}}}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a *very* recent expl3 (January 8th, 2011) for the following code to work (I added `\ior_str_map_inline:nn` a few minutes ago).

```
\RequirePackage{expl3,l3str}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_strange_tmp_bool
\tl_new:N \g_strange_last_line_tl
\tl_new:N \g_strange_line_tl
\int_new:N \g_strange_indentation_int
\int_new:N \g_strange_last_indentation_int
\seq_new:N \g_strange_indentation_seq
\seq_new:N \g_strange_environments_seq
\tl_new:N \l_strange_tmpa_tl
\use:n
  {
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \int_set_eq:NN \tex_endlinechar:D \c_minus_one
    \ior_str_map_inline:nn { \c_job_name_tl }
      {
        \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_strange_last_line_tl \g_strange_line_tl
        \int_gset_eq:NN \g_strange_last_indentation_int \g_strange_indentation_int
        \bool_if:NTF \g_strange_tmp_bool
          {
            \tl_gset_rescan:Nnn \g_strange_line_tl { } {#1~}
            \int_gset:Nn \g_strange_indentation_int
              { \str_length:n {#1} - \exp_args:No \str_length:n { \use:n #1 } }
            \int_compare:nTF { \g_strange_indentation_int > \g_strange_last_indentation_int }
              {
                \seq_gpush:Nx \g_strange_indentation_seq
                  { \int_use:N \g_strange_last_indentation_int }
                \seq_gpush:Nx \g_strange_environments_seq
                  { \str_substr:Nnn \g_strange_last_line_tl {1} {-1} }
                \seq_get:NN \g_strange_environments_seq \l_strange_tmpa_tl
                \exp_args:No \begin { \l_strange_tmpa_tl }
              }
              {
                \tl_use:N \g_strange_last_line_tl
                \int_while_do:nn
                  { \g_strange_indentation_int < \g_strange_last_indentation_int }
                  {
                    \seq_gpop:NN \g_strange_indentation_seq \l_strange_tmpa_tl
                      \int_gset:Nn \g_strange_last_indentation_int \l_strange_tmpa_tl
                    \seq_gpop:NN \g_strange_environments_seq \l_strange_tmpa_tl
                      \exp_args:No \end { \l_strange_tmpa_tl }
                  }
              }
          }
          {
            \str_if_eq:xxT { #1 } { \token_to_str:N \endinput }
              { \bool_gset_true:N \g_strange_tmp_bool }
          }
      }
  }
\endinput

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\document
    We have
    \equation
        A =
        \bmatrix
            a & b \\
            c & d
    where ...
%
```

The trailing `%` at the same indentation level as `\document` is very important. I decided to keep `\\` to separate lines of the matrix, because supporting that would require changing the definition of `\bmatrix`. Here, you simply need to include the code before the document starts, and then stop worrying about it.

Comment: Quite a few bugs, sorry. I'm fixing that.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted.  At best I was hoping for something like "yeah, that'd be nice but it's not going to happen".  I was expecting "go away, the syntax is great".  An actual implementation ... jaw dropping.  Thank you.

Comment: @StephenMcAteer I didn't add good support for comments (i.e., it may or may not work), and starred environment can be trouble. Sharpie's answer is probably the correct one here: use a format such as Pandoc, which can then be converted to LaTeX for typesetting.

Comment: As of September 2015, `\c_job_name_tl` should become `\c_sys_jobname_str`

Answer (score 4):

> Is there an alternative interpreter for LaTeX that has nicer syntax?

In general, TeX is very poor when it comes to "alternative interpreters" due to the fact that writing a program that can understand the grammar of TeX is a very, very hairy problem (and turing-complete too).

Rather than looking for an "alternate implementation" of TeX it's self, try looking for an "alternate grammar" that is close to your ideal input that can be compiled to TeX. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc) has been mentioned as a tool that can parse light-weight markup languages such as Mardown and reStructured Text and convert them to LaTeX. Pandoc is also written in Haskell and pretty easy to extend.

Or, you could roll your own. Perhaps something like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) could be written for LaTeX. CoffeeScript is a language that mashes up the best parts of JavaScript, Python and Ruby syntax yet compiles to JavaScript to spare the overhead of writing a complete language implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where this lies between a comment and an answer. The length pushed it towards the location of the latter.

Here is perhaps a promotion of LaTeX in lieu of your *hate* for its syntax that matches that of your example to a fair degree.

Whenever you define an environment in LaTeX, for example via

```
\newenvironment{myenv}
  {<begin myenv>}% \begin{myenv}
  {<end myenv>}% \end{myenv}
```

it (...LaTeX) defines two commands: `\myenv` and `\endmyenv`. To test this, you'll notice an error in your console when trying to compile the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycmd}{test}% \mycmd
\newenvironment{mycmd}{hi}{there}% \begin{mycmd}...\end{mycmd}
\begin{document}
\mycmd
\end{document}
```

That error being

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \mycmd already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \newenvironment{mycmd}{hi}{there}
```

Even though you didn't define the an *additional* command by the name of `\mycmd`. So, using your code snippet, is it very possible to have LaTeX understand exactly what you're after if you use

```
We have
\equation
  A =
  \bmatrix
    a & b
    c & d
  \endbmatrix
\endequation
where ...
```

whatever your definition for `equation` and `bmatrix` may be (existing and redefined or not). In fact, the following minimal example compiles without problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\begin{document}
We have
\equation
  A =
  \bmatrix
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \endbmatrix
\endequation
where ...
\end{document}
```

As commented by egreg, there are instances where this my be "surprising" and yield output contrary to one'e expectation. However, the extent of this may not influence you without more detail.

Comment: Did you try `\flushright xyz\endflushright`, with some text after `\endflushright`? You'll be surprised. :)

Comment: @egreg: Yes, this is very surprising. I guess there are exclusions to the rule.

Comment: @Werner: accessing environments directly the way you do is undocumented, hence package writers may very well assume that you don't do that. E.g., I could have defined `\newenvironment{mytt}{\ttfamily}{}`. Then doing `\mytt Foo\endmytt Bar` will fail.